# let me know the error in the code and edit it

Tags: scheme

Define a function called symcount that takes a symbol and a list and returns the number of times the symbol occurs in the list. If the list contains sublists, all occurrences should be counted no matter how deeply they are nested.

```
(define syscount(lambda (n x)
  (if (empty? x)
    0
  (if (equal? n (car x))
    (+ 1 syscount(n (cdr x)))))))
```

this is what i have written help me pls

Comment: This looks like a homework, right? You can take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/faq, it will help you getting some answers :)

Comment: You totally changed your question... I reverted the change. If you need help for scheme in general, start reading a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define (syscount n x) 
            (if (null? x) 0 
                  (if (list? (car x))  (+ (syscount n (car x)) (syscount n (cdr x))) 
                         (+ (syscount n (cdr x)) (if (equal? n (car x)) 1 0)))))
```

Output is

> (syscount '1 '(1 2 3)) 
>       1 
>  
>    (syscount '1 '(1 (1 2) 3)) 
>       2 
>   (syscount '1 '(1 (1 2) 1 (1) 3)) 
>       4

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
(define (my-flatten xs)
  (foldr
   (lambda(x acc)
     (if (list? x)
         (append (my-flatten x) acc)
         (cons x acc)))
   (list)
   xs))

(define (my-filter pred xs)
  (let recur ((xs xs)
              (acc (list)))
    (if (empty? xs)
        (reverse acc)
        (if (pred (car xs))
            (recur (cdr xs) (cons (car xs) acc))
            (recur (cdr xs) acc)))))

(define (count-occur s ls)
  (let ((flatten-ls (my-flatten ls)))
    (foldl (lambda (e acc) (if (eq? s e)
                               (+ acc 1)
                               acc))
           0
           flatten-ls)))
```

Test:

```
> (count-occur 'foo (list 1 'foo (list 2 'foo 3 'bar) 4 (list 5 (list 6 'foo)) 7 'foo 8))
4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (symcount n x)
  (cond((null? x) 0)
       ((list? (car x))(symcount n (car x)))
       ((eq? n (car x))(+ 1 (symcount n (cdr x))))
       (else(symcount n (cdr x)))))
```